# jQuery dialog buttons - How to set the dir to be rtl/ltr OR how to place the buttons in left corner of the dialog

Tags: jquery, css, button, dialog, dir

Hi after goggling for a while and going over all previous answers that i found i decided to ask this in here:

I got a dialog which is opened and shown as RTL all the stuff is displayed in RTL, all but the buttons that, now matter what i do stays in the bottom right corner

I want to place the buttons in the button left corner as should be displayed in RTL direction 
I wen over all the Q/A i found in stackoverflow , but nothing have worked for me :/
[code]
    $("#ccDialog").dialog({

```
    minHeight: 100,
    minWidth: 500,
    modal:true,
    resizable:false,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }


        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    ]

});
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove();
$("#ccDialog").height("700");
```

[/code]

I tried to add class / dir attribute, but without success...

Thanks ahead,

Daniel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your css and the dialog buttons will be on the left instead of right.

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset{
float:left;
}
```